# c++ work queues with blocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool, boost-asio, boost-thread

This question should be a little simpler than my last few. I've implemented the following work queue in my program:

Pool.h:

```
// tpool class
// It's always closed. :glasses:
#ifndef __POOL_H
#define __POOL_H
class tpool {
    public:
        tpool( std::size_t tpool_size );
        ~tpool();
        template< typename Task >
        void run_task( Task task ){
        boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lock( mutex_ );
            if( 0 < available_ ) {
                --available_;
                io_service_.post( boost::bind( &tpool::wrap_task, this, boost::function< void() > ( task ) ) );
            }
        }
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
        boost::asio::io_service::work work_;
        boost::thread_group threads_;
        std::size_t available_;
        boost::mutex mutex_;
        void wrap_task( boost::function< void() > task );
};
extern tpool dbpool;
#endif
```

pool.cpp:

```
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include "pool.h"
tpool::tpool( std::size_t tpool_size ) : work_( io_service_ ), available_( tpool_size ) {
    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < tpool_size; ++i ){
        threads_.create_thread( boost::bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_ ) );
    }
}
tpool::~tpool() {
    io_service_.stop();
    try {
        threads_.join_all();
    }
    catch( ... ) {}
}
void tpool::wrap_task( boost::function< void() > task ) {
    // run the supplied task
    try {
        task();
    } // suppress exceptions
    catch( ... ) {
    }
    boost::unique_lock< boost::mutex > lock( mutex_ );
    ++available_;
}
tpool dbpool( 50 );
```

The problem is, though, is that not all my calls to `run_task()` are being completed by worker threads. I'm not sure if it's because it's not entering into the queue or because the task vanishes when the thread that created it exits.

So my question is, is there anything special I have to give to `boost::thread` to make it wait until the queue is unlocked? and what is the expected lifetime of a task entered into a queue? Do the tasks go out of scope when the thread that created them exits? If so, how can I prevent that from happening?

Edit: I've made the following changes to my code:

```
template< typename Task >
void run_task( Task task ){ // add item to the queue
    io_service_.post( boost::bind( &tpool::wrap_task, this, boost::function< void() > ( task ) ) );
}
```

and am now seeing all entries being entered correctly. However, I am left with one lingering question: What is the lifetime of tasks added to the queue? Do they cease to exists once the thread that created them exits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well. That's really quite simple; You're rejecting the tasks posted!

```
template< typename Task >
void run_task(task task){
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock( mutex_ );
    if(0 < available_) {
        --available_;
        io_service_.post(boost::bind(&tpool::wrap_task, this, boost::function< void() > ( task )));
    }
}
```

Note that the `lock` "waits" until the mutex is not owned by a thread. This might already be the case, and possibly when `available_` is already 0. Now the line

```
if(0 < available_) {
```

This line is simply the condition. It's not "magical" because you're holding the `mutex_` locked. (The program doesn't even know that a relation exists between `mutex_` and `available_`). So, if `available_ <= 0` you will just skip posting the job.

---

### Solution #1

You should use the `io_service` to queue for you. This is likely what you wanted to achieve in the first place. Instead of keeping track of "available" threads, `io_service` does the work for you. You control how many threads it may use, by running the `io_service` on as many threads. Simple.

Since `io_service` is already thread-safe, you can do without the lock.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// tpool class
// It's always closed. :glasses:
#ifndef __POOL_H
#define __POOL_H
class tpool {
    public:
        tpool( std::size_t tpool_size );
        ~tpool();

        template<typename Task>
        void run_task(Task task){
            io_service_.post(task);
        }
    private:
        // note the order of destruction of members
        boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
        boost::asio::io_service::work work_;

        boost::thread_group threads_;
};

extern tpool dbpool;
#endif

#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
//#include "pool.h"

tpool::tpool(std::size_t tpool_size) : work_(io_service_) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < tpool_size; ++i)
    {
        threads_.create_thread( 
                boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_) 
            );
    }
}

tpool::~tpool() {
    io_service_.stop();

    try {
        threads_.join_all();
    }
    catch(...) {}
}

void foo() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }
void bar() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

int main() {
    tpool dbpool(50);

    dbpool.run_task(foo);
    dbpool.run_task(bar);

    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

For shutdown purposes, you will want to enable "clearing" the `io_service::work` object, otherwise your pool will never exit.

---

### Solution #2

Don't use `io_service`, instead roll your own queue implementation with a condition variable to notify a worker thread of new work being posted. Again, the number of workers is determined by the number of threads in the group.

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::phoenix::arg_names;

class thread_pool
{
  private:
      mutex mx;
      condition_variable cv;

      typedef function<void()> job_t;
      std::deque<job_t> _queue;

      thread_group pool;

      boost::atomic_bool shutdown;
      static void worker_thread(thread_pool& q)
      {
          while (auto job = q.dequeue())
              (*job)();
      }

  public:
      thread_pool() : shutdown(false) {
          for (unsigned i = 0; i < boost::thread::hardware_concurrency(); ++i)
              pool.create_thread(bind(worker_thread, ref(*this)));
      }

      void enqueue(job_t job) 
      {
          lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
          _queue.push_back(std::move(job));

          cv.notify_one();
      }

      optional<job_t> dequeue() 
      {
          unique_lock<mutex> lk(mx);
          namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

          cv.wait(lk, phx::ref(shutdown) || !phx::empty(phx::ref(_queue)));

          if (_queue.empty())
              return none;

          auto job = std::move(_queue.front());
          _queue.pop_front();

          return std::move(job);
      }

      ~thread_pool()
      {
          shutdown = true;
          {
              lock_guard<mutex> lk(mx);
              cv.notify_all();
          }

          pool.join_all();
      }
};

void the_work(int id)
{
    std::cout << "worker " << id << " entered\n";

    // no more synchronization; the pool size determines max concurrency
    std::cout << "worker " << id << " start work\n";
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "worker " << id << " done\n";
}

int main()
{
    thread_pool pool; // uses 1 thread per core

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        pool.enqueue(bind(the_work, i));
}
```

Comment: I see... Is wrap_task not necessary then? I ask, because I was using wrap_task to allow me to post tasks that include arguments with boost::bind, a la dbpool.run_task( boost::bind( some_func, some_arg ) );
Which would normally be called like: some_func( some_arg );

Comment: To the comment that I missed earlier: you can still post bind expressions with the `run_task` member function. (It's just that the counting is now the responsibility of the queue, not of the task threads. Which is better in my opinion). Cheers.

Comment: @Sehe Could you please elaborate "For shutdown purposes, you will want to enable "clearing" the io_service::work object, otherwise your pool will never exit."?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi as long as a `work` is registered on the io_service it will never spontaneously complete. So for clean shutdowns often `work` instances are created dynamically (think `unique_ptr<work>` or `boost::optional<work>`)

Comment: PSA: newer asio comes with `asio::thread_pool` which does all the work-guard stuff internally as well. Also, newer asio work-guards have a `reset()` member so you no longer require `unique_ptr` or `optional` to get that functionality.