# Why does my Wait method hang indefinitely?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using this snippet of code to handle a pool of threads. After calling RunTask a number of times (where the task in question is a method that sleeps for 5 seconds), I then call Wait() in an attempt to wait for all the threads to finish. The code hangs in this Wait() mehhod. I suspect its my management of the condition variable, but I can't figure it out.

```
class lthThreadHandler {
public:
    lthThreadHandler(int pool_size)
    {
        mAvailable = pool_size;
        mRunning = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < pool_size; ++i)
            mThreads.create_thread(boost::bind(&lthThreadHandler::pool_main, this));
    }

    template<typename Task>
    void RunTask(Task task)
    {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mMutex);

        // If no threads are available, then return.
        if (0 == mAvailable)
            return;

        // Decrement count, indicating thread is no longer available.
        --mAvailable;

        // Set task and signal condition variable so that a worker thread will
        // wake up andl use the task.
        mTasks.push(boost::function<void()>(task));
        mCondition.notify_one();
    }

    void Wait() {
        try {
            mThreads.join_all();
        }
        // Suppress all exceptions.
        catch (...) {
        }
    }

    /// @brief Entry point for pool threads.
    void pool_main() {
        while (mRunning) {
            // Wait on condition variable while the task is empty and the pool is
            // still running.
            boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(mMutex);
            while (mTasks.empty() && mRunning) {
                mCondition.wait(lock);
            }
            // If pool is no longer running, break out.
            if (!mRunning)
                break;

            // Copy task locally and remove from the queue.  This is done within
            // its own scope so that the task object is destructed immediately
            // after running the task.  This is useful in the event that the
            // function contains shared_ptr arguments bound via bind.
            {
                boost::function<void()> task = mTasks.front();
                mTasks.pop();

                lock.unlock();

                // Run the task.
                try {
                    task();
                }
                // Suppress all exceptions.
                catch (...) {
                }
            }

            // Task has finished, so increment count of available threads.
            lock.lock();
            ++mAvailable;
        } // while mRunning
    }
private:
    std::queue<boost::function<void()> > mTasks;
    boost::thread_group mThreads;
    std::size_t mAvailable;
    boost::mutex mMutex;
    boost::condition_variable mCondition;
    bool mRunning;
};
```

This code snippet come from another SO answer: [Thread pool using boost asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215395/thread-pool-using-boost-asio/12267138#12267138)

Comment: Do you have access to C++11? You may want an atomic boolean.

Comment: How and where does `mRunning` get set to `false`?

Comment: Does `mCondition.wait(lock);` keep `mMutex` locked for a long time (or indefinitely)? Something like that could cause trouble.

Comment: @AndyG mRunning gets set to false in the destructor, not shown here

Comment: @AndyG No C++11. This is in a legacy system still on VS2010

Comment: Then how do you make shure, that the destructor is called? When is it called? Have you placed a breakpoint, where running is set to false? - because your wait is not hanging indefinitely, your condition to leave the wait part is never fullfulled!

Comment: `catch(...)` without rethrowing is a stupid idea, in particular on MS Windows, where it catches some other errors that are not C++ exceptions. Replace it with `catch(exception const&)` and log the error. That said, provide a minimal but complete example! As per the posting guidelines, your question is off-topic without it.

Answer (score 0):

`Wait` hangs indefinitely because the threads all run an infinite loop as long as you don't clear `mRunning`. Even if you did [it might change your pet into a bag of popcorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of the data race.

---

So. Basically you butchered someone's perfectly fine taskqueue/threadpool implementation. Mostly by renaming things idly¹ and then

- removing the crucial destructor
- adding a `Wait()` that just joins threads without doing anything to cause these threads to finish.
- adding race conditions on the `mRunning` flag

Even if you put the original destructor logic into `Wait()` keep in mind you'll actually have a race condition where there is no guarantee that the posted tasks will run before the (main) thread resets the `mRunning` flag.

#### What Now?

I suggest you don't meddle with the code.

- If there is something you need it to do, ask a constructive question like "How can I make sure that XXX" instead of "Why does my broken code not YYY"
- If you want *to learn* ask about the original implementation, or about a single isolated change

#### Alternatives

I have a few thread similar pools that you might find easier to understand on [SO] so you could compare:

- [Calculating the sum of a large vector in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048539/calculating-the-sum-of-a-large-vector-in-parallel/28049353#28049353) (links to two implementations)

I answered a similar question once before (in response to the fact that you're trying to `join_all` from a member function instead of the destructor:

- [asio::io_service and thread_group lifecycle issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304286/asioio-service-and-thread-group-lifecycle-issue/34306588?s=6|0.0000#34306588)

That answer could be very helpful to you explaining why that kind of function is tricky.

---

¹ `pool_main`, really? Thread manager, really? All the names were originally better chosen.