# Boost asio io_service mutithreading poor performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm playing with cellular automatons and trying to boost my application performance by using multi threading. But I've some interesting results. I'm not really know why this is happening and what I'm missing...

So my aim is to process a big buffer of data as fast as I can. In my example I have a big (20000 x 20000) bool array and transforming it into an image (one bool value to one pixel). This process can be done in parallel; there isn't any dependency between the pixels. I divide the bool array into `threadCount` number of blocks, start a new thread for each block, let them run, and wait for them to finish.

I assumed that with more threads I`ll get a bit better runtime. (I do not use an unrealistic thread count, just between one and the logical core number.)

So I wrote this:

```
typedef std::size_t Size;
typedef std::vector<bool> Data;
typedef std::vector<Data> History;

class RenderTask
{
  public:
    typedef void result_type;

  public:
    RenderTask(Ppm& ppm,
               const Ppm::Pixel& fColor)
      : mPpm(ppm),
        mForegroundColor(fColor)
    {
    }

    void operator()(const History& history,
                    const Size minIdxX,
                    const Size countX,
                    const Size minIdxY,
                    const Size countY)
    {
      const Size maxIdxX(minIdxX + countX);
      const Size maxIdxY(minIdxY + countY);
      for(Size y(minIdxY); y < maxIdxY; ++y)
      {
        for(Size x(minIdxX); x < maxIdxX; ++x)
        {
          if(history[y][x])
          {
            mPpm.setPixel(x, y, mForegroundColor);
          }
        }
      }
    }

  private:
    Ppm& mPpm;
    const Ppm::Pixel mForegroundColor;
};

void render(const History& history,
            Ppm& ppm,
            const Ppm::Pixel& fColor,
            const Size threadCount)
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::thread_group threads;
  for(Size i(0); i < threadCount; ++i)
  {
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run,
                                      &io_service));
  }

  RenderTask task(ppm, fColor);
  io_service.reset();

  const Size count(history.size() / threadCount);
  const Size rem(history.size() % threadCount);
  Size minIdxY(0);
  for(Size i(0); i < threadCount; ++i)
  {
    const bool addRemainders(rem && i == threadCount - 1);
    io_service.post(boost::bind(task,
                                boost::cref(history),
                                0,
                                history.front().size(),
                                minIdxY,
                                addRemainders ? count + rem : count));
    minIdxY += count;
  }

  threads.join_all();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const Size rule(parseNumber<Size>(argv[1]));
  const Size size(parseNumber<Size>(argv[2]));
  const Size iteration(parseNumber<Size>(argv[3]));
  const Size threadCount(clamp(1,
                               static_cast<Size>(boost::thread::physical_concurrency())
                               parseNumber<Size>(argv[4])));
  ...
  History history(iteration, Data(size, false));
  history.front()[size / 2] = true;
  ...
  process(history, rule, threadCount);
  ...
  Ppm ppm(history.front().size(), history.size(), Ppm::Pixel(30, 30, 30));
  std::cout << "rendering... ";
  t.start();
  render(history, ppm, Ppm::Pixel(200, 200, 200),  threadCount);
  t.stop();
  std::cout << t.ms() << " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

But when I ran the program with different number of threads I got the following:

I have no idea why the more cores could not result in better performance. With two cores it's a bit better, but interestingly with three cores it almost as the same as with one core... These value are averages:

```
ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 1 test.ppm
rendering... 554.95 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 2 test.ppm
rendering... 289.75 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 3 test.ppm
rendering... 555.37 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 4 test.ppm
rendering... 554.23 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 5 test.ppm
rendering... 564.23 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 6 test.ppm
rendering... 551.82 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 7 test.ppm
rendering... 555.22 ms

ThreadingTest.exe 110 20000 20000 8 test.ppm
rendering... 510.12 ms
```

What can causes this? Am I using the io_service in a wrong fashion? There is no I/O operation involved, just pure memory.

I have eight cores in my machine with 16 GB of RAM.

For additional details, here is the outline of the Ppm class:

```
class Ppm
{
  public:
    struct Pixel
    {
      typedef unsigned char ChannelType;
      ChannelType  mRed, mGreen, mBlue;
      ...
    };

    typedef std::vector<Pixel> ImageData;

    Ppm( const SizeType width
         , const SizeType height
         , const Pixel& color = Pixel() )
      : mWidth( width )
      , mHeight( height )
      , mImageData( mWidth * mHeight, color )
    { }

    void setPixel( SizeType x, SizeType y, const Pixel& p )
    {
      mImageData[x + y * mWidth] = p;
    }
    ...
  private:
    const SizeType mWidth;
    const SizeType mHeight;
    ImageData mImageData;
};
```

**UPDATE**

After your valuable comments I changed the approach a lot and wrote this:
Now I'm using pure c++'11 stuff and there is no boost involved anymore..

```
class ThreadPool
{
  public:
    ThreadPool(const Size threadCount);
    ~ThreadPool();

  public:
    template<class T>
    void addTask(T task);
    void wait();

  private:
    bool mStopped;
    Size mRunningCount;
    std::vector<std::thread> mWorkers;
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> mTasks;
    std::mutex mMutex;
    std::condition_variable mCondition;
    std::condition_variable mFinishCondition;
};

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(const Size threadCount)
  : mStopped(false),
    mRunningCount(0)
{
  for (Size i(0); i < threadCount; ++i)
  {
    mWorkers.push_back(std::thread([this]()
      {
        std::function<void()> task;
        while(true)
        {
          {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mMutex);

            this->mCondition.wait(lock, [this] { return this->mStopped ||
                                                        !this->mTasks.empty();
                                               });
            if(this->mStopped)
            {
              return;
            }

            ++this->mRunningCount;
            task = this->mTasks.front();
            this->mTasks.pop_front();
          }

          task();

          {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->mMutex);
            --this->mRunningCount;
          }

          this->mFinishCondition.notify_all();
      }
    }));
  }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool()
{
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    mStopped = true;
    mCondition.notify_all();
  }

  for(auto& worker : mWorkers)
  {
    worker.join();
  }
}

template<class T>
void ThreadPool::addTask(T task)
{
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
    mTasks.push_back(std::function<void()>(task));
  }
  mCondition.notify_one();
}

void ThreadPool::wait()
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);
  mFinishCondition.wait(lock, [this]()
    {
      return mTasks.empty() && mRunningCount == 0;
    });
}
```

Now the performance is OK; using more threads the runtime gets faster...
But something is not good with the wait method. I'm using it in this way:

```
ThreadPool pool(threadCount);
for(Size i(1); i < iteration; ++i)
{
  Size count(history.front().size() / threadCount);
  Size rem(history.front().size() % threadCount);
  Size minIdx(0);
  for(Size n(0); n < threadCount; ++n)
  {
    pool.addTask(std::bind(ECATask(rule),
                           std::cref(history[i-1]),
                           std::ref(history[i]),
                           minIdx,
                           (rem && n == threadCount - 1) ?
                             count + rem :
                             count));
    minIdx += count;
  }
  pool.wait();
}
```

The problem with this in not clear yet, but it seems the `pool.wait()` sometimes does not wait for all the current tasks to be finished and code starts a new iteration... Can you please do a code review for me? :)

Comment: Which `clamp` is being used in the code -- [`std::clamp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp)? If so, the order of the parameters appears to be incorrect.  Also, what value is returned by `boost::thread::physical_concurrency()`?

Comment: What is `Ppm`? Are you sure you can modify it from different threads at the same time when calling `mPpm.setPixel(x, y, mForegroundColor);`?

Comment: Try timing the thread creation loop too.  Creating threads isn't the fastest thing in the world and most thread pools tend to be long lived because of the expense in creating them.

Comment: I agree with @UKMonkey ... You should time only the concurrent operation even thread.wait can cause delays, use multiple runs of exe for same config to get an average result. beyond that boost's  thread CPU affinity is something that you might have to tweak through native_handle to see better results(?)

Comment: @G.M. It's my own `clamp()` function and works fine. The `physical_concurrency()` returns 8 on my machine.

@VTT `Ppm` is my own image class. It's stores `Pixel`'s in an `std::vector`. I'll update the question with an outline of this class.. I know that the `std::vector` is not thread safe but in this case the size of the vector does not changes, all the elements are allocated before the `setpixel` writes them and two threads does not writes the same pixel..

Comment: I suspect your bottleneck is in dealing with the graphics subsystem. Does the graphics library have an async interface?

Comment: @UKMonkey tried to time the thread creation and it`s around 0.05 ms for creating one thread.

Comment: @Richard Hodges there is no graphics subsystem involved. I have only one array of booleans (input data) and I iterate over this data one-by-one and modify a `Pixel` value in the `Ppm` object's vector. 
There is a one-to-one correspondence between the booleans in the input and the pixels in the `Ppm` image.

So the steps is to read a value from the bool vector and depending on it's value I set the pixel to (0,0,0) or (255,255,255) in the ppm's internal vector by calling `setPixel` Thats all :)

Comment: Well, if all else fails, you'll have to get the profiller out and see what it tells you is running slowly.

Comment: maybe unrelated, but there is a race condition between resetting the io_service and posting tasks to it. Consider using an `io_service::work` object. In the current code, it could well be that `run()` is returning in a number of the threads, meaning that the program is not as parallel as you might think.

Answer (score 1):

There's quite some indication that you're confused about io_service:

```
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::thread_group threads;
  for(Size i(0); i < threadCount; ++i)
  {
    threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run
                                      , &io_service));
  }

  RenderTask task(ppm, fColor);
  io_service.reset();
```

The issues:

- you should not call reset() there
- the threads start before the io_service has any work. This means `run()` completes IMMEDIATELY, exiting the thread.

So the whole thing is a giant race condition: if you're lucky some of the threads (possibly none) will not start `io_service::run()` before the first task gets enqueued, so it will all *seem to work*.

Look at this answer for a good side-by-side of a thread-pool without using Boost Asio, and one with Boost Asio: [c++ work queues with blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925256/c-work-queues-with-blocking/25928221#25928221)

> Note the use of `io_service::work` to avoid prematurely exiting the worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading is always slow because of resource sharing, period.

The moment two threads share some resource, even a simple integer variable, they will run slower than in the case when they are completely isolated.

Of course, if both of them only read the variable, and it stays constant it isn't really sharing. To share some information it must be created (eg. saved to some variable) in one thread and then received (eg. read from said variable) in another.

All these instances of sharing slow some or all involved threads down. Since programs (CPUs basically) operate with memory, every share boils down to one or more regions of RAM. The more RAM regions are shared, the larger they are, and **most importantly** the more often in happens, the slower the threads that are involved will run.

A perfect application is the one that has only a single thread. With a few exceptions, any problem that can be broken down and executed in several concurrent **processes** will be solved faster that way than by creating the same amount of threads in a single process. Exceptions, of course are the cases when, in order to start solving the problem we must do some costly 'initialization' first, the outcome of which will stay constant and be available to all threads. Or, in case of a always running service (daemon): a dynamic, evolving state that would have to be shared regardless (imagine a database server). In my experience, those are the most common reasons of making application multi-threaded instead of multi-process.

Given the said above, if the threads are necessary, we must strive to isolate them as much as possible. By sharing in between them as less data as possible.

In your case, you have an `io_service` that is shared by multiple threads due to each thread calling `run()` on the the same instance. Addition of threads to the same `io_service` will have diminishing returns and ultimately will lead to the waste of CPU resources. You are better off creating multiple `io_service` instances and having an async chit-chat between them. Even then it won't be as good as having completely separate threads bu you will see an incredible gains compared to your original approach.

Regarding **asio** itself. Having almost a decade of experience with it I can confidently say that it still has too many opportunities for improvement. Especially when it comes to the heavy use of 'do it all' mutexes in places where some non-locking data structures would have sufficed.